# Colorbox modal of any URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I'm trying to create a modal that opens any URL, where the `a` tag has a specific class.

In the colorbox docs it has this as an example:

```
// ColorBox can accept a function in place of a static value:
$("a.gallery").colorbox({rel: 'gal', title: function(){
  var url = $(this).attr('href');
  return '<a href="' + url + '" target="_blank">Open In New Window</a>';
}});
```

My HTML structure is:

" class="modal" rel="gal">

```
        <h2 id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

        <div class="entry">
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        </div>

</div>
```

and my JS is:

```
jQuery(".modal").colorbox({rel: 'gal', title: function(){
  var url = jQuery(this).attr('href');
  return '<a href="' + url + '" target="_blank">Open In New Window</a>';
}});
```

But it's just not triggering - I'm not getting any console JS errors - can anyone see what's wrong here?

Comment: What isn't triggering? Does your function for the property `title` execute? Does the element with class "modal" exist in the DOM when you execute the `colorbox()` method?

Comment: perhaps I've misinterpreted what the function does, but to answer your question: yes the modal exists and the title function doesn't seem to fire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Totally misinterpreted the function - if you are trying to do what I outline in the opening post then use the iframe functionality.

e.g.

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery(".modal").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:425, innerHeight:344});    
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `colorbox()` method on `<div>` elements, which are not valid elements for that method. This method may only be used on `<a>` elements.

Answer (score 0):

parent.$.colorbox.resize({ width: 460, height: 130 });